# Is possible to add an implementation stub in this case?

Tags: c++, wrapper, directive, software-design

I have a library `X`, and I'm adding wrappers around another library, say `Y`, in C++.

In all the source files, every time I add implementations using `Y` functionalities, I guard everything with an identifier called `X_WITH_Y_WRAPPERS`.  Now, consider a source file where I have implemented a function `Foo` :

```
#ifdef X_WITH_Y_WRAPPERS
void Foo(const Xtype& arg1, const Xtype& arg2, Ytype& arg3){
//implementation
}
#endif
```

here with `Xtype` I mean that the type of the variable is a type of my original library `X`, while `Ytype` is a type related to the other library.

So far so good. Now, a developer asked:

> "Add a default implementation which throws an error saying the
> function `Foo` needs `Y` to be installed."

I'd do the following:

```
#ifdef X_WITH_Y_WRAPPERS
void Foo(const Xtype& arg1, const Xtype& arg2, Ytype& arg3)  
//implementation using library `Y` inside
}
#else
void Foo(const Xtype& arg1, const Xtype& arg2, Ytype& arg3)
//assert
}
#endif
```

but I don't understand how this can make sense, as `Ytype arg3` needs the library `Y` to be installed in order to be passed as an argument, right? I think the requested change would make sense only if the third input argument doesn't depend on `Y`library. Am I correct?

Comment: Wouldn't the "no Y" version just have 2 args? You can't use the 3rd arg in the body if you don't have the type. Add another #ifdef where you use the constructor.

Comment: @John3136 Uhm no, there's no version with 3 args. Also, what di you mean with "Add another #ifdef where you use the constructor"? I don't see which constructor you're referring to, I'm sorry

Comment: Sorry I read Foo as a constructor. But same applies. You need a 2 arg version of Foo (with no Ytype) and an ifdef on the call to only use the 3rd arg if X_WITH_Y_WRAPPERS. Think of the implementation of Foo. You can't use Ytype throughout it you don't have the Y lib.